# Removing some parts from rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
       Text
75    21 sto ma - ... I am using python...
34    19 sti ma - how to print ...
23    17 sto ma - asked yesterday...
19    two dictionaries in a single expression ...
28    Taking union of dict...
                            ...
```

I would like to remove, where there are, the following: `nn sto ma -` `or nn sti ma -`, in order to have:

```
       Text
75    ... I am using python...
34    how to print ...
23    asked yesterday...
19    two dictionaries in a single expression ...
28    Taking union of dict...
```

The format is `number+number, sto or sti + ma`.

Could you please help me to remove this part from the rows? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Series.str.replace` and catch your pattern:

Explanation:

- `\d{2}`: two numbers
- `\s`: a whitespace
- `[io]`: an `i` or `o`

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('\d{2}\sst[io]\sma\s-\s', '')

                                           Text
75                     ... I am using python...
34                             how to print ...
23                           asked yesterday...
19  two dictionaries in a single expression ...
28                      Taking union of dict...
```

Comment: Thank you s much @Erfan.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try with `split`

```
df.Text=df.Text.str.split('-',n=1).str[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you @YOBEN_S. Do you think the code might also remove some parts that do not start with numbers? I would like to avoid to delete accidentally part of text, for example if I have `Hi - how was your day? `